# Failure to Boot to bios and video failure

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, bios, hardware-failure

Ok... so let me start with some of the computers history...

A year or two ago, the integrated video on the computer stopped showing anything on the monitor for some wired reason that is unknown. This was after I had been switching out a few graphics cards for testing purposes. Well I solved this by just leaving in one of the old graphics cards.

The graphics card had about the same performance as the integrated video did, so no problem there. I installed the drivers for the old graphics card I had and it worked entirely fine and there was no irregularity's in the computers performance after boot. This computer had been booted up and turned off many times with no problem until recently.

Then one day the DVI cord was disconnected from the graphics card and for some reason the video was no longer working. The next time I booted it up, it was still giving the normal posting beep even with video not being projected on the monitor. So I tried it with out the video card in it as it had been a year or two ago. This time it was REALLY bad and it did not post. As soon as it was turned on it shut itself off in a few seconds.

I have tried many combinations since then and there has been no progress what so ever. I will give this one last shot before I assume that some how the motherboard failed and the computer pretty much just has to be chucked.

I think the real problem is that I had no idea what was actually happening to the the computer during all this. I just made little makeshift repairs that were never permanent. Almost anything could gone wrong. The RAM could be bad, the hard drive could have failed, the power supply could be shot, or the whole motherboard could have just died.

What would I need to do to figure out the failed BIOS and video issue?

Comment: I hate to ask, but since the DVI was disconnected when you found it, did you check the other end of the connection to make sure it was correctly seated? if it was loose, that would explain 100% of your problem, at least as I understand it.

Comment: No I checked that many times and it is screwed in tightly (the way DVIs do) and it also is screwed in to the video card too.

Comment: I also tried to day the integrated again, (that uses an HDMI) no luck of course.

Answer (score 1):

A bad hard drive should have no impact on your issue - it simply means your drive won't be visible in BIOS or the OS.
Failed RAM can definitely prevent your computer from passing POST but the speaker should not sound the regular beep; this varies by motherboard but in my experience bad/no RAM should result in very quick successive beeps. *It might be a good idea* for you to take out your RAM and see if you observe this behaviour. You'll at least be able to eliminate or narrow down your problem.
One thing you should double-check is to make sure that your CPU heatsink fan is plugged in and working. If something is wrong and your CPU heats up very quickly the computer should shut itself off. It's unlikely that the DVI cable affected this, but check it anyway.
You are also correct in thinking that a bad power supply can be the problem. Now is a great time to get another one and put it in - see what happens.

Beyond that I can only think that it's an issue with your motherboard. Doesn't necessarily mean it's dead... there could even be a grounding issue somewhere? A loose screw or something. Check your case and try reseating all your components and cables.
If that fails, try a new motherboard if that's a possibility. You don't want to just "chuck" the computer if there are still some good parts left!

Best of luck.